# Aplicaciones menos seguras gmail junio 2022

Tags: phpmailer, gmail

Hola chicos tengo varias aplicaciones desarrolladas en múltiples plataformas/lenguajes que utilizan de alguna manera el servicio de login o correo de Gmail.

El problema es que hace poco todas dejaron de funcionar al mismo tiempo ya que las políticas de Gmail y el uso de aplicaciones, cambio por lo tanto la opción de: ***aplicaciones menos seguras*** ya no funcionan.

Entonces asumiendo que en mis plataformas/desarrollo el/los códigos están bien, Existe alguna forma de evadir o reconfigurar mi correo o los accesos que uso para continuar usando el servicio de gmail???

Comment: Estas app passwords no funcionan? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: @Alfabravo relativamente lo acabo de encontrar tambien XD